# Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

I am getting very strange error while trying to modify an item within the `ConcurrentDictionary`:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tripple> SeenEnoughDict =   
               new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tripple>();  
private struct Tripple
{
    public int prev_antenna;
    public int num_of_times_seen;
    public Timer timer;

    // ctor
    public Tripple(int antenna, Timer tm)
    {
        this.prev_antenna = antenna;
        this.num_of_times_seen = 1;
        this.timer = tm;
    }
} 
// several items were added to the dictionary

 Parallel.ForEach(_myReaderTC.Cast<Tag>(), t => {
     // attempting to modify the item  
     // t.ID is string    
     SeenEnoughDict[t.ID].num_of_times_seen = SeenEnoughDict[t.ID].num_of_times_seen + 1; 
}
```

last line throws the error:

```
Error 149   Cannot modify the return value of  
'System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<string,Tripple>.this[string]'   
because it is not a variable
```

What is interesting about this error, is that http://pastebin.com/0cQJMcUD works without issues.
Recently, I have converted my solution from 2010 to 2013. In 2010, I have used Concurrency collection that was backported from .NET 4 to 3.5 (I got it from NuGet).

Comment: Try making the returned value a class. I'll be you can modify its values then. The compiler is helping you here because you're returning a struct and modifying it, you won't get the value updates like you think you will.

Comment: And creating mutable structs is generally a bad idea for precisely this reason. I'd advise you to use public *properties* backed by private *fields* though, instead of exposing the fields publicly - and to start following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: @focuspark - If you can write it as an answer. I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @newprint Adam Robinson has a great write up below for you to mark as answer. Thanks anyways :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your type is a `struct`. Generally speaking, unless you know you have a specific reason to create a value type (a `struct`), you should really be creating a `class` instead. If you're ever going to modify something about it (i.e. what you're creating doesn't represent a discreet "value" and changing something doesn't make it inherently something else), you should *definitely* be using a `class`. In terms of solving your problem, simply replacing `struct` with `class` will do the trick.

However, I would also recommend exposing properties instead of fields. The general idiom in .NET languages is to use `private` backing fields and to expose them outside of the declaring class when necessary by using properties. So instead of this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int MyValue;
}
```

You'd do this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private int myValue;

    public int MyValue
    {
        get { return myValue; }
        set { myValue = value; }
    }
}
```

I realize this is a little wordy, but for simple properties (simple get/set operations where there isn't anything beyond setting the value of a field required) you can use "auto properties"

```
public class Foo
{
    public int MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

For simple get/set operations, the property syntax is no more verbose but still gives you the flexibility and separation of concerns that properties afford you.

Lastly I would suggest adopting PascalCase names, since that is what you'll find in most .NET languages.

After all of those changes, your class would look like:

```
private class Tripple
{
    public int PrevAntenna { get; set; }
    public int NumOfTimesSeen { get; set; }
    public Timer Timer { get; set; }

    // ctor
    public Tripple(int antenna, Timer tm)
    {
        this.PrevAntenna = antenna;
        this.NumOfTimesSeen = 1;
        this.Timer = tm;
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that your class could use a more meaningful name (unless "Tripple" has some industry-specific meaning in your line of work that I'm just not aware of), but hopefully this is enough to be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I was thinking that `struct`s work the same they they work in C/C++. I was completely wrong !